# NSwag & Extension Code - How to ensure it's placed at the start of the file?

Tags: c#, typescript, nswag

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 backend, and a Typescript 3.8 front end.

I'm attempting to tell NSwag to inject authorization headers, as per this page in the documentation: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/TypeScriptClientGenerator#inject-an-authorization-header

(My `extensionCode` file is, exactly, what's provided there)

When NSwag builds my output TypeScript file, however, my `extensionCode` is places at the *bottom* of the file. That means that the classes generated above can't reference it, and I get TypeScript compilation errors. If I manually move my code to the top, it works.

I see in the NSwag code that  there seems to be a way to get the extension code to render at the top as expected, and it seem to do with `extendedClasses`, but for the life of me I can't get it to work. I've also tried adding `extends generated.[Class Name]` as described in a couple places, but that didn't help either (or, more likely, I was doing it wrong).

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get this working?

**Edit:** Almost forgot, here's a link to my nswag.json file: https://gist.github.com/mattgrande/075f05177191bf8daffbf51609e40267

Comment: Having the exact same issue, searching a fix for an hour already without success

Comment: @AdrianIorgu - Please let me know if you get it working!

Comment: See also: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2801

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out. For me, there were two issues:

1. I had a configurationClass that was actually an interface.
2. There were comments above my base class, which is apparently a no-no.

Comment: No comments allowed above class definition <- that saved me some serious time, ty!

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue and found Matt Grande's solution didn't work for me. So here are a list of things to check which caused my problem.

1. Any comment with the word class in it above the base class seem to cause a problem.
2. There cannot be any indentation before the start of your class declaration - This either leads to the generator adding your code at the bottom or doing `export export class BaseClass`. (Copying from the docs adds indentation to the file)
3. Having an interface as your `configrationClass` seems to work but generates the configuration interface at the bottom of the file - This is still valid Typescript.